# I am getting following crash report in Google Play console in my Air application

Tags: actionscript-3, crash, google-play-console

I am receiving following crash report from Google Play Console in my Air application. I am using following technology for my application.

Platform - Flash Adobe Animate CC (AIR SDK 33.1.1.217)
Language - As3
Using this ANE's -

```
com.mesmotronic.ane.fullscreen (version - 1.2.6), 
                   com.distriqt.playservices.Base (version - 17.1.0),
                   com.distriqt.Core (version - 5.1.346),
                   com.distriqt.InAppBilling (version - 9.1.026)
                   com.distriqt.AppGroupDefaults (version - 4.1.058)
                   com.distriqt.ApplicationRater (version - 5.3.008)
                   com.google.android.play (version - 1.0.018)
                   com.distriqt.Share (version - 6.0.056)
                   androidx.core (version - 1.2.0)
```

Following is the trace log of the crash report

```
"main" tid=1 Native
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x75615af0 self=0x7e34a14c00
  | sysTid=3034 nice=-10 cgrp=pnpmgr_top_app sched=0/0 handle=0x7ebb3ce548
  | state=S schedstat=( 204289685604 4280499392 32970 ) utm=19071 stm=1357 core=4 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fe3296000-0x7fe3298000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 000000000006f6d0  /system/lib64/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 0000000000029168  /system/lib64/libc.so (ioctl+136)
  #02  pc 000000000001820c  /vendor/lib64/libsrv_um.so (PVRSRVBridgeCall+84)
  #03  pc 000000000000e564  /vendor/lib64/libsrv_um.so (???)
  #04  pc 00000000000e8d7c  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so (???)
  #05  pc 00000000000b0f5c  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so (???)
  #06  pc 000000000002ad60  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so (???)
  #07  pc 0000000000026084  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so (???)
  #08  pc 0000000000025b1c  /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so (glDrawElements+140)
  #09  pc 00000000002ce2d0  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #10  pc 00000000005207b4  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #11  pc 0000000000520438  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #12  pc 0000000000515780  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #13  pc 000000000042d744  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #14  pc 0000000000437d94  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #15  pc 00000000004363f0  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #16  pc 0000000000437b6c  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #17  pc 00000000004363f0  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #18  pc 0000000000437b6c  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #19  pc 00000000004363f0  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #20  pc 0000000000437b6c  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #21  pc 00000000004363f0  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #22  pc 0000000000437b6c  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #23  pc 00000000004363f0  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #24  pc 0000000000437b6c  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #25  pc 00000000004363f0  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #26  pc 0000000000437b6c  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #27  pc 00000000004363f0  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #28  pc 000000000040e208  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #29  pc 000000000040f900  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #30  pc 00000000003607b4  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #31  pc 00000000003613b4  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #32  pc 00000000003612d0  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #33  pc 000000000035d554  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #34  pc 000000000048c430  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #35  pc 00000000004af33c  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #36  pc 00000000004aff24  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #37  pc 000000000025efd8  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #38  pc 000000000026231c  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)
  #39  pc 0000000000265c10  /data/app/com.internetdesignzone.aesopfables-h8qjL3lg8u_cwSKndGDpHg==/lib/arm64/libCore.so (???)


at com.adobe.air.customHandler.callTimeoutFunction (Native method)
  at com.adobe.air.customHandler.handleMessage (customHandler.java:22)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6758)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:497)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:912)
```

I found this crash report in Android 9 version.

Comment: I searched by **com.adobe.air.customHandler** (you should've done the same prior to asking), found a reported bug, and also there seems to be a solution: https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/AIR-4198519

Comment: @Organis this link seems to describe issues related to playing sounds via `Sound.play()` within Android ANE environment. The proposed workaround is to use ANESounds, whatever it is.

Comment: Hi, @Oraganis thank you for your suggestion.
I have tried DigitalStrawberry's ANE for sound playing. They are playing short sounds like small tapping sound using following code.

soundFile = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("introVideo-en.mp3");
soundId = ANESounds.instance.loadSound(soundFile);
streamId = ANESounds.instance.playSound(soundId);

but i am not able to play long sound using same code. It stops after certain seconds in between. Please help , how to play long length mp3 files using this code ?